# Add a NsProgressIndicator to a special row in NstableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm very confused because multi NsProgressIndicators in NstableView don't work correctly,The addSubview method always add the progress cell to the last row in the tableview,not exactly
the row index i want,here is some simple code:

The NsTableView DataSource have two members:

```
@interface tableModel : NSObject {

NSString *name;
NsProgressIndicator *progressobj;
}

@property(retain) NSString* name;
@property(retain) NsProgressIndicator *progressobj;
```

And i write a custom cell class:"ProgressCell",

Progresscell.m:

```
- copyWithZone : (NSZone *)zone
{
ProgressCell *cell = (ProgressCell *)[ super copyWithZone:zone ];
cell->progress = [ progress retain ];
return cell;
}

- (void) drawInteriorWithFrame : (NSRect) cellFrame 
                     inView: (NSView *) controlView
{
[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];

if(progress==nil)
{
    return;
}       
if(![progress superview])
{
    [controlView addSubview: progress];

}       
    [progress setFrame: cellFrame];
    [progress sizeToFit];   
}

- (void)setProgress:(NsProgressIndicator *)newProgress
{
[newProgress retain];
[progress release];
progress = newProgress; 
[progress sizeToFit];
}
```

Now it's the time to add some tableModel objects to the table view datasource:

```
NSString *str=@"test";
tableModel *tablemodel=[[tableModel alloc] initWithPriority:[str retain] andProgress:nil];
[tableArrays addObject:tablemodel];
[tableView reloadData];
```

The progress member is nil because i don't want to display a progressindicator at beginning,
Guess i have a edit button,set up an action as below:

```
NsProgressIndicator * progress = [[[NsProgressIndicator alloc] init] autorelease];
[progress setIndeterminate: NO];
[progress setMinValue:0];
[progress setMaxValue:100];
tableModel * zMyDataObj= [[self tableArrays] objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]];
zMyDataObj.progressobj=[progress retain];
[tableView reloadData];
```

The willDisplayCell delegate method is:

```
tableModel * zMyDataObj= [[self tableArrays] objectAtIndex:pRow];
if([zMyDataObj progressobj]!=nil)
{
[cell setProgress:[zMyDataObj progressobj]];
}
```

But when i click the edit button, A new NsProgressindicator is always added to the last row,not the selected row,the addSubView method is definitely not suitable for this case,So i want to seek a best solution to set up a connection between a NsProgressIndicator and a special row,thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `cellFrame` is the problem:

```
[progress setFrame: cellFrame];
```

The `cellFrame` refers to the position of the cell inside the tableView and it has a specific `origin(x,y)`. If you would like to position the progress indicator you should create a new rect for it and set the origin inside the `cellRect`.

```
NSMakeRect((cellFrame.size.width - 20.f)/2, cellFrame.size.height - 20.f), 20.f, 20.f)
```